# Retrieve Data from Resultset using SQL Server in Android

Tags: java, android, sql-server, resultset

I'm trying to display the data I query from an SQL Server. Please help me.

Here's my code :

```
final String username = pref.getString("username", ""); // Data from SharedPreferences File
try {
    String query_select = "SELECT * from teller_info where teller_name = '"+username+"'";
    PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query_select);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        String teller_id = rs.getString("teller_id");
        TextView view_userID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._userID);
        view_userID.setText(teller_id);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My problem is nothing will return. The `TextView` I set does not change.

Comment: What is the issue? Please specify. If its an error then post a stack trace.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Nothing will return. The TextView wont be changed

Comment: Is teller_id set to anything?

Comment: @Mathemats Yes teller_id is a column from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is part of an Android App this is not about the data retrieval but displaying that data. As far as I can see the SQL Part seems fine.

To display data however you would have to add a [listener of some sort](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).
That listener would have to update your TextView. Then you would update your View e.g. via [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

I suggest you go through some tutorials on how to update TextViews - there is a good one on javacodegeeks dot com /android/core/widget/textview/android-textview-example/

To post a more specific answer I would need more code (ideally the whole activity + layout.xml). It would be good to know when your text should change because a Button would get a onClickListener whereas a TextView could get a AddTextChangedListener.

Example of a OnClickListener:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDatabse("some input");

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. You give me some idea on how to do it

Comment: If it helped you please accept the answer. If you need any tutorial recommendation just ask, since I just were in the same spot as you a few weeks ago.